# Question about installation for Readthedocs and a related question about using markdown with the Sphinx for a RTD site

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, myst

Please bear with me as I am a tech writer, not a developer. I actually have two questions, but they are related...

Q1. We want to create a documentation project on GitHub and hosted in ReadTheDocs. If I understand correctly, to generate the documentation, ReadTheDocs uses software installed on the ReadTheDocs server, not on my machine, so strictly speaking I don't need to install anything locally? I could just upload files directly to GitHub and make all the edits there? (As far as I understand, installing python locally is only needed if I want to see a local version of the Documentation website, which is highly desirable, but not essential? I am eventually planning on doing this, but first I would like to understand better what is going on.)

Q2. I am experimenting with hosting our ReadTheDocs documentation using the Sphinx generator. However, I want to work with markdown files, not RST files. As far as I understand, to enable this I need to "install the myst_parser extension". My doubt is if the answer to my previous question happens to be "yes" then doesn't that mean this extension needs to be installed on the ReadTheDocs server? How do I do this?

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: ReadTheDocs support of Markdown was based on Mkdocs, https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-mkdocs.html, long before Sphinx MyST support was created. So, to get started you just need to learn how to use Mkdocs.

Comment: Thanks Lex. Actually I already tried Mkdocs months ago. After a lot of trial and error (Googling for setup information that was not in the RTD tutorial) I got a working project, but when I regenerated it recently it would not build. I have also seen quite a few posts of others having build issues with the Mkdocs generator on RTD. I came to the conclusion that it is not as stable as Sphinx. In any case, I would like to know the answers to my two questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add extensions to a Sphinx project without looking at the configuration code for your Sphinx project. As such, you would have to take some steps into development - but perhaps you can enjoy this tutorial for getting started with Sphinx? I think it's made with technical writers in mind, too: https://techwritingmatters.com/documenting-with-sphinx-tutorial-intro-overview

**Q1:**

I recommend that you follow the above tutorial so you are able to build a Sphinx project locally while you are setting up extensions. Following the tutorial will get you familiar with basic concepts that will make everything easier and less mythical.

Once you have setup your GitHub project and wrestled with the configuration code changes required in Q2, you can enter a workflow where you edit files on GitHub and Read the Docs does the rest.

No local builds required, no command line etc. Just pure writing.

**Q2:**

You will also need to create a so-called `requirements.txt` and configure your Read the Docs project to install the Python packages in that file.

You can configure Read the Docs in two ways:

1. Method 1: Via the Dashboard UI, you will find an option for requirements.txt
2. Method 2: By creating a `readthedocs.yaml` specifying the following:

```yaml
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
   configuration: docs/conf.py

# Optionally declare the Python requirements required to build your docs
python:
   install:
   - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

You need to add a `requirements.txt` because `myst_parser` is distributed as a Python Package and you need to tell Read the Docs how to get it (and which version). Create a file `docs/requirements.txt` containing the following:

```
Sphinx>=5,<6
myst_parser>=0.18,<0.19
```

Notice the version logic here: We are telling Read the Docs that we want Sphinx in the 5.x series and myst_parser in 0.18.x series. This is to avoid sudden build failures in the future.

You are responsible for updating versions of Sphinx and extensions. You can also remove the version pinning, but then your project might fail to build suddenly in case new incompatible releases come out.

Finally, will need to edit your `conf.py` file in order to add the `myst_parser` extension. You should find the line containing the `extensions` variable and change that.

```py
extensions = [
    "myst_parser",
]
```

You will probably use the above instructions again in the future since there are many good extensions and themes for Sphinx.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thanks benjaoming that is really helpful. I had already done the edits in conf.py and readthedocs.yaml but did not know I also had to enter the myst_parser version in the requirements file...I will try that now.

Comment: All working! Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome!! Happy to help! Can you mark the answer correct so I can get my StackOverflow self-confidence dose? :D